# Creating index on sas table

Tags: indexing, sas

I have a table on Linux server, and I want to create index on it in SAS EG on my PC (Win). I got a mistake:

> Error: File XXX.xxx cannot be updated because its encoding does not match the session encoding or the file is in a format native to another host.

How can I avoid it?
my code:

```
proc datasets library=mylib;
modify table;
index create names=(field1 field2 field3);
run;
```

Comment: Then you need to be on the same system as the table. You can modify your setting if needed, via the config file but that's usually not a great solution because you're working on a different server for a reason I assume.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are trying to create the index on a data set that has a different encoding than the current session of EG.

```
proc options option=encoding;
run;
```

will list the encoding used by the EG session

```
proc contents data=mylib.table:
run;
```

will show the encoding on the dataset

If they don't match,  the easiest thing to do is to create a copy of this dataset with an encoding that matches the session and create the index on that.

```
libname mylib '/location';
libname mylib2 '/location2' outencoding='UTF-8'; /* should match session encoding */
proc copy noclone in=mylib out=mylib2;
   select table;
run;
```

This may not work if you need to preserve the encoding to avoid information loss.  In that case you will have to go through some configuration changes to make EG invoke a SAS session with the proper encoding. This might help,  but I have not done this myself:

http://support.sas.com/kb/51/586.html

Since you are just dealing with an issue due to different OS, this will do I think:

```
libname mylib '/location';
libname mylib2 '/location2`;
proc copy noclone in=mylib out=mylib2;
   select table;
run;
```

followed by

```
proc datasets library=mylib2;
modify table;
index create names=(field1 field2 field3);
run;
```

Comment: I suppose, that the problem is mostly connected with different operation systems, WIN and Linux. And I cannot copy libname, need exactly this.